# invalid resx file. Could not find file ..\..\My Project\Resources.resx

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I was working with a web project in the .NET 2.0 Framework, but when i open the project in the 4.0 Framework it gives me invalid resx file error. The way my project works is that i have an empty solution, then i add a project, then a website. So it is a solution with two projects in it, one with the VB script, the other with the aspx pages

Comment: Which of the two projects has the error? It sounds like you may have moved one of the projects from its original location. My Project is usually relative to the project file instead of referencing a location in a different directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use IIS you might have forgotten to edit the framework in the settings.
if you moved it its just the filepath that is invalid. try to use Utility.RawApplicationPath and then you just go from there.

```
Utility.RawApplicationPath"/myResourceFolder/myResources.resx"
```

I use my resources like that and I never had any problems ;)

Hope this helped you.

Comment: You were right i had forgotten my framework settings. i went to the properties of my web app and changed the build target framework to 4.0. It works now thanks

Comment: Your welcome.
I recently had that same problem ;)
Glad to help out ^.^